# Dimmer switch replacing 3-wire switch not working

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I need some help to get my dimmer switch working with my light. I have power coming into the junction box and then leaving to go to a second outlet and the light. The original light was a 3-wired light with a fan, but the new light is just a light, no fan.

How do my wires need to be connected to make this happen? Both outlets continue to work just fine, but I can't get the switch to work with the lights. The dimmer is a Lutron 600w dimmer. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your original is not a 3 wire light, but what amounts to a fan with a light kit installed.

2 wires are for the light and one for the fan.

Generally they are wired WHITE - NEUTRAL to [FAN / LIGHT] , BLACK - HOT for [LIGHT] . RED - HOT for FAN.

*Is there another Switch on a different wall same wall that operated the original  Fan/Light Combination?*

- This would tell us that the RED is a Traveler for a 3 Way Switch.

You will need to provide some more details:

- Measure voltage between Copper Wire [GND] and WHITE.
- Measure voltage between Copper Wire [GND] and BLACK.
- Measure voltage between Copper Wire [GND] and RED.

Comment: This is the only switch for the light.

Comment: @junta you will need to provide the voltage readings as I have outlined..perhaps a few others (white to black, white to red, black to red) but lets start with what I have listed in my answer. Post the results as an edit to your qwuestion.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct dimmer also. Is this fixture LED, CFL or incandescent?